# Why might an N MOSFET switch output flip with no change in gate voltage (and then stick)?

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, mosfet, switching

In lots of places, we use a simple N-FET switch to turn on/off 24V outputs. We use a 30V rated part and stay well under the power/current limits.

We've started to see recently however a couple of instances of LEDs turning on of their own accord when wired as below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1oHZ1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In a non-failed state, if the MCU pin goes high, the FET is turned on, the voltage at the Drain (LED's cathode) goes to 0V and the LED lights.
In the failed state, even when the MCU output is 0V, the LED lights and the Drain voltage is ~0.15V. A high output still pulls the Drain to 0V, but it returns to 0.15V when the FET is switched back off.

I realise that when the switch is open the drain of the FET is floating rather than in a defined state, but how is the LED turning on when there is nowhere for current to flow to?

The [datasheet for the part we are using](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/FDN359BN-80801.pdf) does stipulate a "Zero Gate Voltage Drain Current" (no FET is an ideal switch) but it's measured in micro-amps which is orders of magnitude too small to light the LED.
Using the datasheet we can also see that the part is being used within spec as we don't come close to the maximum voltages/currents.

Can anyone suggest what might be going on?

Comment: Is there a facility to disconnect the MCU from the MOSFET gate? Where does the 24 volts come from? What interference might be on the 24 volt power line? What is the physical (cabling) distance between MOSFET and LED? Does the MCU and MOSFET driver share a common 0 volt supply?

Comment: The MCU and FET are both on the same PCB so not easy to disconnect. R2 in the above schematic could be removed if there's something to be ganied from doing so?

Comment: That's 40% answered.

Comment: Sorry, fell victim to the 'enter to post' rather than 'new line'. Then spent more time editing than the allowable window...

24V is the shared supply for the whole system. There's nothing isolated so the derived MCU voltage (3V3) shares the same 0V. The supply itself comes from an industrial supply when in situ, but the PCB in question also shows the same behaviour when powered with a bench supply.

The LED is in an external button, but this is only down 5cm of cable so physically quite close.

Comment: Fairchild don't make MOSFETs anymore - they are made by ON semi (unless that part of the fairchild portfolio has been sold off by them) so, maybe someone somewhere decided to pick an alternative supply ans screwed up in some way.

Comment: Having just done a quick check, I believe this part is still manufactured by ON, under the same P/N: https://www.onsemi.com/products/discretes-drivers/mosfets/fdn359bn Their own uploaded datasheet (found on the linked page) is just the original Fairchild document with a cover page. The doesn't preclude the wrong part having been fitted, but the correct part is still widely available

Comment: Have you checked the voltage on the gate of the transistor when the mcu output is high and low?

Comment: Switching noise on the 24V supply would take you pretty close to the FET 30V rating ... or over. How confident are you that it's quiet?

Comment: @RoyC yes, the MCU is correctly setting the gate voltage.

Comment: @BrianDrummond it's currently under test with a bench supply that I think can be expected to be near perfect. Where it was in the unit previously the PSU is possibly less likely to be perfect, but there are other 24V powered devices in the system that would have shown an error if the supply reached close to 30V.

Comment: Is your MCU output configured as open drain? That would leave the gate floating when not being driven. Note also, from the datasheet, the graph showing ON resistance vs Vgs. At 3V3 logic levels, that resistance could be quite high. This may cause some heating in the FET, which in turn could damage it after some period of time.

Comment: MCU is push/pull so gate doesn't float. I'v also left a unit with the FET switched on for a couple of hours now and the FET isn't even warm to the touch

Answer (score 1):

Add resistant between gate and source to make sure it switch off. try to measure Vgs.
If Vgs is 0 and circuit still on your mosfet is broken.